# Missing resolveStrategy breaks DSL when executed from runnable jar

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jvm

I'm using the  [Groovy Spreadsheet Builder](https://github.com/dsl-builders/spreadsheet) within one of my Grails projects to export some data as Excel file.

Everything works great until I create a runnable jar (using `gradle assemble`) and use this.

I'm using the builder within a service like this:

```
class ExcelService {
    ...
    void export(OutputStream outputStream) {
       ...
       PoiSpreadsheetBuilder.create(outputStream).build {
          apply ExcelStylesheet
          ...
       } 
    }
    ...
}
```

When I try to export my data from the app started using the generated jar I will get the following `MissingMethodException`:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: my.package.ExcelService.apply() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class)
```

The (Java) interface of SpreadsheetBuilder looks like this:

```
public interface SpreadsheetBuilder {
  void build(@DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = WorkbookDefinition.class) @ClosureParams(value = FromString.class, options = "builders.dsl.spreadsheet.builder.api.WorkbookDefinition") Configurer<WorkbookDefinition> workbookDefinition);
}
```

While debugging the execution of the code and the jar I found the difference while stepping through `invokeMethod()` of `ClosureMetaClass`.

When `closure.getResolveStrategy();` in the working version is called `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST` will be returned. Debugging the jar, the result will be `0` so that the `MissingMethodException` will be thrown later due to the wrong resolve strategy.

For now I have no idea how to solve this problem.

What is/could be the reason for this behavior?
What can I do to solve this issue?

I'm using Grails 3.3.8 with Java OpenJDK 1.8.0_192.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to support JDK 7, you could upgrade to Groovy Spreadsheet Builder 2.0.0.RC1 which is only JDK 8 compatible but appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`@ClosureParams` and `@DelegatesTo` are applicable to parameters of type `groovy.lang.Closure`.  In this case, you have applied it to `Configurer<WorkbookDefinition>`.

Comment: The interface comes from the third party lib. It's not within my codebase and everthing is working fine when using `gradle bootRun` - it just crashes when I create  and run the created jar. What could/should I do?